# Source tables from JSON API extraction

Tags: database-design, json

Trying to implement an API extraction that dumps the results from JSON apis daily in a postgres db. The goal for these data is to be used in analysis. Afterwards I will handle those using dbt to do the modeling part (*extracting the JSON values*).

Example JSON values from an object representing a task on a task management system:

```json
{
 gid: 1234, // Unique id for the resource
 updated_at: "Wed, 22 Mar 2023 08:53:46 GMT",
 ... rest of the attributes
}
```

My current strategy is storing those in tables with this schema

| gid | info::jsonb | updated_at::timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | {...} | Wed, 22 Mar 2023 08:53:46 GMT |

If the extraction is to happen once a day every day, does the strategy of surrogate key of (gid, updated_at) sound ok to judge if the insert should happen or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that seems reasonable.
Since you'll be scanning the jsonb on each pass each time for *gid* and *updated_at*, you'll want to create a GIN index for this purpose, e.g.

```
CREATE INDEX api_gid ON api USING GIN ((info-> 'gid'));
```

Ideally, you could create an index on both *gid* and *updated_at*, but that requires use of an extension called `btree_gin`.  Without the extension, you could try creating a second index on `info->'updated_at'`, but it would probably not get used.. depends on what else the query needs to do.

If you can install the `btree_gin` extension, then this syntax would work:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON items USING GIN (account_id, keywords);
```